# When should I use remove_reference and add_reference?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm looking at [VC10's] unique_ptr and they do a couple things I don't understand:

```
typedef typename tr1::remove_reference<_Dx>::type _Dx_noref;

_Dx_noref& get_deleter()
    {   // return reference to deleter
    return (_Mydel);
    }

unique_ptr(pointer _Ptr,
    typename _If<tr1::is_reference<_Dx>::value, _Dx,
        const typename tr1::remove_reference<_Dx>::type&>::_Type _Dt)
    : _Mybase(_Ptr, _Dt)
    {   // construct with pointer and (maybe const) deleter&
    }

typename tr1::add_reference<_Ty>::type operator*() const
    {   // return reference to object
    return (*this->_Myptr);
    }
```

Wouldn't just writing _Dx& or _Ty& be the same thing?

I actually do understand why they did it here though:

```
unique_ptr(pointer _Ptr, typename tr1::remove_reference<_Dx>::type&& _Dt)
    : _Mybase(_Ptr, _STD move(_Dt))
    {   // construct by moving deleter
    }
```

Comment: @KerrekSB: Sometimes it is a lot easier to learn from a single well explained example than from a whole textbook. Furthermore, most textbooks won't even cover this material, because they were written rvalue-references existed in the language. This is a valid and well asked question, that I can imagine being useful for a lot of people who are learning C++.

Comment: @KerrekSB This isn't exactly something I can look up. Even if I did happen across the rule that prompted the ctor to need to do what it does I probably wouldn't associate it here without seeing any examples. On another note, can you please stop flaming all my posts? You clearly have a problem with me (I don't care why).

Comment: Sorry, Dave, not at all -- apologies for that. The thing is that those are very specific tools that you'd only really use inside a template library, and which you could only appreciate in a template context, so I felt than an answer would require too much 'build-up' in order to be useful. I don't mean to flame or hurt you, apologies again for that, and I look forward to your next question!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## `get_deleter`

Any reference is removed from the return type, then a reference is added back. In conformant C++11, adding a `&` to an existing `&` (or `&&`) produces a `&`. In C++03 however, that would be forming a reference to reference type, which was illegal. Likely MSVC is using the old rules, or that code was written when it did and remains because it is harmless.

## constructor

Here they remove the reference, add `const`, and then add the reference back, to be passing by `const` reference. This is because adding `const` directly to a reference type does *nothing*! (§8.3.2/1) In either C++11 or C++03, the parameter declaration would be valid but would not add a `const`, if the reference weren't removed and replaced.

## `operator*`

This is essentially the same as `get_deleter`, but they went about it a different way, and `_Ty` cannot be a reference type to begin with. It looks to me like `_Ty&` would suffice, but it's their prerogative.

Comment: Awesome breakdown man - thank you. I would upvote multiple times if I could, especially after others flamed for no apparent reason imo. Incidentally, why can't _Ty be a reference type to begin with?

Comment: @Dave: Well, `_Ty` *shouldn't* be a reference type because you can't have a pointer to a reference. (8.3.2/5) I'm not checking whether there's some quirk that helpfully strips a reference in that case, but otherwise `unique_ptr`'s member typedef `pointer` would be ill-formed.

Comment: @Dave : No one flamed you; taking what was intended to be constructive criticism so poorly is just silly.

Comment: @ildjarn Viewing that as constructive is just silly. However, this is the internet and everyone is going to interpret what they read differently with different contexts. C'est la vie.

Comment: @Dave : Exactly, and having thin skin will get you nowhere. ;-]

Comment: For what it's worth, in my opinion the "having thin skin will get you nowhere" approach is a recipe for failure for the human race.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Having a thin skin gets you nowhere on the cutting edge… the real issue is whether this question was cutting edge when it was asked, but that's certainly changed since January and continues to be a little iffy.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example, possibly archetypal, for why we need `remove_reference`, in the implementation of `std::move`: The goal is to return an rvalue-reference type, based on the *deduced* type of the function argument.

Example: `Foo x; move(x);` Here `move(x)` should return a type `Foo&&`. But the argument of `move` is an expression of type `Foo&`. So how can the `move` function deduce the right type?

The first attempt is to use ordinary template argument deduction and use a cast:

```
template <typename T> T && move(??? x) { return static_cast<T&&>(x); }
```

But what should go into `???`? If we say `T x`, then `T` will be deduced as `Foo&`; if we say `T & x`, then `T = Foo`, and if we say `T && x`, it won't match at all. The second version, `T & x`, appears to be useful.

But then the function doesn't work on rvalues to begin with (e.g. `move(Foo(...))`. In this case, we want `T && x` so that `T = Foo` and `T&& = Foo&&` as desired. We could have two overloads, but having multiple overloads is undesirable because it increases complexity needlessly. And finally, if someone were to specify the template paramete explicitly as `move<Foo&>(x)`, the function would *never* work, because when `T = Foo&`, then `T&& = Foo&` as well.

So in comes `remove_reference`:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type && move(T && x)
{
    return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type &&>(x);
}
```

First off, the new reference collapsing rules imply that `T` is deduces as either `Foo&` or `Foo&&` in the two cases. Then, `remove_reference` strips the reference and gives type `Foo` in any case, and adding `&&` makes the desired `Foo&&` return type.

In an oversimplified summary: we need `remove_reference` because `(Foo&)&&` is `Foo&` and not `Foo&&`. If you ever write template code that needs the base type of a template paramter that could be deduced as either `U&` or `U&&`, you can use this model.

Answer (score 1):

`template class add_reference` has specialization for `void`, `const void` and `const volatile void` because reference of `void type (void&)` is not allowed. If `_Ty&` is used, it would generate a compilation error when `_Ty = void`.