# template function and boost::remove_reference

Tags: c++, boost

I'm tracking down a C++ compiler error which I can't figure out. I've reduced it to this code:

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/remove_reference.hpp>

template<typename T> inline const T bar( T in )
{
    typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME boost::remove_reference<T>::type nonref;
    const nonref* inPtr = &in;
    return *inPtr;
}

class Foo
{
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    const Foo& ref = bar< Foo& >( foo );
}
```

which results in:

```
tt.cpp: In function ‘const T bar(T) [with T = Foo&]’:
tt.cpp:19:39:   instantiated from here
tt.cpp:9:13: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘Foo&’ from expression of type ‘const nonref {aka const Foo}’
```

What's the actual issue here? Why is the const missing in the return value? I need the remove_reference since the actual code requires it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying `const` to a reference type does nothing. You need to make the template argument `const foo &`, or else remove the reference and then add back both `const` *and* the reference in the function signature itself.

See also [When should I use remove_reference and add_reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8860400/153285) particularly the second paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Using VisualStudio 2008 I get the following error

`error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'const nonref' to 'Foo &'`

Changing bat to

```
template<typename T> inline const typename boost::remove_reference<T>::type& bar( T in )
{
    typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME boost::remove_reference<T>::type nonref;
    const nonref* inPtr = &in;
    return *inPtr;
}
```

fixes this and the code compiles.

Comment: But, subtly, the return type of the function still isn't `const`, which is probably not what she intends.

Comment: Well… now it returns by value, not reference. Perhaps coincidentally this is another context where `const` is ignored. Personally I'd rethink a design that requires `const` to be added underneath a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Returning `const T` from your function doesn't do what you are expecting. From your code I understand that you expect it to return `const Foo&`, which is *a reference to an immutable object of type `Foo`*.

But when `T` is `Foo&`, the expression `const T` means *an immutable reference to an object of type `Foo`*. Since the references are always immutable, the const part is just dropped (according to the paragraph 8.3.2 of the spec)! That is, your function returns `Foo&` and not `const Foo&` and that's what the compiler tries to tell you.